# Make the hovered element go darker, but all the other elements go lighter

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not sure if this is now possible with CSS, but when I hover over an element I want it to go darker (opacity of 0.9) and all the other elements to go lighter (opacity of 0.1). When no elements are being hovered, I'd like all elements to have an opacity of 0.5. the markup would look something like this:

```
<div class="box a"></div>
<div class="box b"></div>
<div class="box c"></div>
<div class="box d"></div>
```

[image]

The layout of the boxes is irrelevant.

Maybe JS/jQuery will be needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this, it can be done with css. Try the code below, it will give you a good idea how to make what you want.

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.wrap:hover .box:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.wrap:hover .box:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
  <div class="box d"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible with CSS. But can easy be performed with js and little help of jquery:

```js
$(".box").hover(
 function() {
   $(".box").each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity", 0.1);
    });
   $(this).css("opacity", 0.9);
  },
  function() {
   $(".box").each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity", 0.5);
    });
  }
);
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box a">a</div>
<br>
<div class="box b">a</div>
<br>
<div class="box c">a</div>
<br>
<div class="box d">a</div>
```

Comment: Dont use jQuery for something simple

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward `.hover()` method can give you the intended behaviour.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
jQuery('.box').hover(function(){
  jQuery(this).addClass('darken'); /* darken hovered element */
  jQuery('.box').not(jQuery(this)).addClass('lighten'); /* lighten all other elements */
}, function(){
  jQuery('.box').removeClass('darken lighten'); /* reset after hover out */
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: #0072ff;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .7s;
  opacity: .5;
}

.darken {
  opacity: .9;
}

.lighten {
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box a"></div>
<div class="box b"></div>
<div class="box c"></div>
<div class="box d"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Really js to achieve this?! You need just a basic CSS knowledge. :)

```css
.Container {
  cursor: default;
}

.Container:hover .Element:not(:hover) {
 opacity: 0.1;
}


.Element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 200ms;
}


.Element:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Element"></div>
  <div class="Element"></div>
  <div class="Element"></div>
  <div class="Element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `Really js to achieve this?!` comment? the OP is not saying it's needed, he's simply asking if it is.

Comment: Both of your solutions are not quite the desired result, atm. this can't be done with pure CSS, will probably be possible with the CSS4.

Comment: @VXp I don't see how this does not result in what the OP asked for?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Of course it's not. Changing the opacity of all the boxes on the parent/wrap hover isn't the desired solution. Like I said, can't be done with pure CSS atm., JS/jQuery solutions are more appropriate.

Comment: @VXp I don't know how you know what the desired solution is for the OP, any way you are allowed to have your own opinion, but he marked my answer so I guess it solved the OP problems and met his requirements

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen answer solved my problem exactly.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It was just a friendly comment. I was just "negatively" impressionate by the UncaughtTypeError jquery solution.

Comment: @24ma13wg If that is your solution then you should edit your question accordingly because atm. they don't match.